# Cannot load an image file as texture using C++ and SFML 2.1

Tags: c++, visual-studio, textures, sfml

I am trying to output an image onto the screen using SFML 2.1, C++, and MS Visual Studio Professional 2013. I am getting an unexpected error when trying to load a file into a texture. It outputs a whole bunch of random characters. I'm sure if its how I configured the SFML library with Visual Studio or a problem with the code. Can anyone solve this problem? Thanks.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like when I run the program (https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMdLT.png):
[image]

This is my code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    sf::RenderWindow window;
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My First SFML Game!"); // initializing

    sf::Texture jetTexture;
    sf::Sprite jetImage;

    // Getting Error here!
    if (!jetTexture.loadFromFile("fighter jet.png"))
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not load fighter jet.png");

    jetImage.setTexture(jetTexture);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        window.draw(jetImage);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For all configuration properties, they look like this:

Linker -> General (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZg7P.png):
[image]

Linker -> Input (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tPaB.png):
[image]

**Please note that if I did not configured the SFML library as I did, then I would be getting an error from my system saying `msvcr110d.dll is missing`.

Comment: I just used VS Express 2013 with yout exact source code and I get the same error! So it's not just your machine. I'm trying to figure out why it's happening!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I managed to fix this, here is what you need to do:

1. Set your SUBSYSTEM to WINDOWS: [image]
2. Add "sfml-main.lib" to your libraries: [image]
3. Change your Runtime library to /MD. This is because you're not using the debug versions of the SFML 2.1 libraries (and probably can't in VS2013). [image]
4. Make sure your "fighter jet.png" image is in the right place. By default Visual Studio uses the Project Directory as the working directory. So put the png in the same folder as your vcxproj file.

Comment: Fixed my problem with drawing sprites also ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the picture is in the execution directory of your program ?
You should avoid spaces in file's name (fighter_jet.png).

If you're not sure about execution directory, try with absolute path (to be sure it's a path problem, and not a picture's problem).

I hope it helps.

I've tried this code on my system (Xcode - OSX), with one of my picture, and it works.
Have you tried with another picture ?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    sf::RenderWindow window;
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "My First SFML Game!"); // initializing

    sf::Texture jetTexture;
    sf::Sprite jetImage;

    // Getting Error here!
    if (!jetTexture.loadFromFile("fighter jet.png"))
        throw std::runtime_error("Could not load fighter jet.png");

    jetImage.setTexture(jetTexture);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        window.draw(jetImage);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried both cases (absolute path and removing spaces in file name) that you suggested and am still getting the same error

Comment: OK, I've added a game loop, could you try ?

Comment: (EDIT) Can you try with another picture ? The (updated) code works on my system, with one of my pictures.

Comment: See the update. I appreciate your help. I'm beginning to think that the problem is with version of SFML I downloaded. I got version 2.1 (32 bit) for MS Visual C++ 2011 but I have MS Visual Studio Professional 2013. What do you think?

Comment: Sorry, I have no MSVC skill, I works with C::B under Windows, and I had troubles at the beginning too, to find the *right* SFML library... You should try with the "hello world"-code, the one involving no picture, and with other SFML lib 32/64, till you find the right one.

Comment: I already tried hello world and the sample code suggested when configuring SFML with Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013 and they both work. Its a weird problem. Thanks for your help. +1

Comment: @Alias You should use a version of SFML compiled with the same compiler that you use for your program, here the one with VS2013. You can either compile SFML yourself (best option, ther eis a tutorial on the official website) or find an already compiled package.